# Voltage reference to drive multiple thermistors - high precision with op amp to supply current, or just generic voltage ref?

Tags: temperature, thermistor, voltage-reference

I would like to drive 8 thermistors in parallel.
They will be driven from 2.5V in a voltage divider. This will be about 20mA current draw.

I will be using a ratiometric measurement where the ADC reference voltage will be the voltage supplying the thermistors.

Is it better to use a high precision reference voltage, with an op-amp follower to supply the required current, or just to use a generic reference voltage with a high current output like https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1761sff.pdf

I would like to design for easiest calibration across parts. Am I right to assume that if I am ratiometric then it does not matter?
The voltage ref, ADC and measurement board will also be far away from the thermistors and not exposed to any significant temperature swing

Comment: Seems like a lot of current for 8 thermistors.  What is the part number for your thermistor?

Comment: If you are using radiometric measurement the accuracy of the voltage reference is not critical.